# Do scars generally continue to undergo beneficial changes after maturation?

Tags: histology, tissue-repair

I understand that succumbing *wound healing*, a modulated scar would go through a process of *scar healing* which I understand to be *remodulation* and *maturation*.

Do scars generally continue to evolve in beneficial ways throughout the life of a human?
That is to ask; might it be that a scar's evolution could be comprised of two major stages "primary" and "secondary" and that the primary stage is consisted of *remodulation* and *maturation* and the secondary is comprised of "post maturation" evolution which could last during all life of a human?

<sub>In general, scars do get changed after being "healed", at least by general bodily changes from aging effecting all tissues in general (including the scar tissue), but there might also be a "post maturation evolution" as well.</sub>

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I think you're asking if scar remodeling continues indefinitely? No, it does not, but there is a two stage remodeling, the first short, the second over as long as a few years.

Comment: I think my terminology is similar but enough different: I know there are only "remodeling" and "maturation" (which corresponds to the "second remodeling") you mentioned ; any of the way --- yes, I ask if there is healing beyond `maturation` or `secondremodeling`.

Comment: I had a serious burn on my arm 2” by 1” and it has shrunk over time - some 40 years...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer — it is being considered for closure. —–– Some suggestions: 1) Based on the answer you accepted, "healing" doesn't seem to have been the correct choice of words — you could reword your questions to something like 'Is scar tissue altered after maturation?'. 2) Also "succumbing" doesn't seem to make sense in this context — did you mean something else?

Comment: @tyersome hello to you ; I have did a similar change; I think it's good.

Comment: I agree that looks better, but I'm going to make some edits of your grammar and to make your title more concise. ——— However, succumb means "fail to resist some negative force", so as far as I can tell "succumbing wound healing" doesn't really mean anything. Did you by any chance mean "secondary to"? Also, what do you mean by a "modulated scar"? If that has a specific meaning please provide a link. (Note: It is important to use generally accepted terminology to avoid confusion, so it would be great if you were to read up on this subject a bit and make sure you are using the correct words!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collagen that holds together scar tissue is continuously degraded and replaced. ([Plastic and Reconstructive Surgery, 1976](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/175389)) If collagen synthesis slows down, due to [scurvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scurvy) for example, old wounds can in theory reopen. Historic records of sea voyages contain descriptions of long-healed wounds opening back up in scurvy victims, and these cases are cited authoritatively in some papers (e.g. [Annals NYAS 1961](https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1961.tb46115.x)), but it is difficult to test experimentally.
I would describe this more as 'maintenance' of the scar, rather than as 'continuous healing', but it may be of interest to you.